# Batch file to export file to Network Share

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a .bat file to run the RVTools for our VCenter and I need to have the file exported out to a network share.  I can only seem to get the file to store locally.  How can I modify the following code?

```
"C:\Program Files\RobWare\RVTools\"RVTools.exe -passthroughAuth -s vcenter.domain.local -c   ExportAll2xls -d c:\
```

**Edit 1:** When I try running is with the -d \share\path (both with and without quotes) the RVTools program starts to launch, but then is closes out and the file is no created. I don't get any errors either.

**Edit 2:**  I think it's a credential thing, as I was able to access a different network path - how can I pass my network admin credentials through with this command?

Comment: Have you tried `-d \\Share\path`? if that doesn't work, have it create the file locally and then move it to the network share.

Comment: I have tried that - but I'm trying to get the process automated.  Currently I manually run the export every Monday, but it would be nice if I could take my hands out of it.

Comment: Ok. So, what happened when you did that? Did it work, not work. Any error messages? Update your question with as much detail as possible to get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `net use` to map a drive letter to the share will allow the software to save to a drive letter, while allowing you to use your credentials to access the server.

Check `net use /?` for the different ways to specify the username.

This assumes that drive z: is not in use already.

```
net use z: "\\server\share" /user:[domain\]user password
"C:\Program Files\RobWare\RVTools\RVTools.exe" -passthroughAuth -s vcenter.domain.local -c   ExportAll2xls -d z:\
net use z: /delete
```